# Problem in the sentences connected with "and"

Tags: grammar

My question is about when two sentences are connected by "and". I want to know if both sentences have the same subject, should I omit the subject of the second one?

For example:

> It has global view and is aware of everything.

Is this sentence correct or should I add subject in the second part of the sentence?

My second question is when in the first side there is an infinitive. For example:

> She refused to go out and **(to) drink** a cup of tea.

Should I use the infinitive form of "drink" or I should use "drink"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely omit the subject if the first sentence is short enough.  In your provided example there is no issue.  It's never wrong to include the subject for maximum clarity, though, which would be best in certain contexts like instructions, legal-related, etc.

Your second example is different.

> I went out and drank a cup of tea.

This creates an implication that the two things are related - by not repeating the subject pronoun a "blending" effect is happening.  "Going out and drinking a cup of tea" would be a single action (consisting of sub-actions) to a typical listener/reader without additional context.

> She refused to go out and to drink a cup of tea.

Repeating the *to* here can sound like you are trying to break that blend/implication, or make it clear that 2 separate things were refused.  If you are angry with this person for not going out and drinking a cup of tea, you may say this as an emphasizing device to make her "list of trangressions" bigger.  (The ultimate emphasis is created by saying "She refused to go out and she refused to drink a cup of tea!").

Comment: Thanks. So in a normal condition, when there is no special emphasis, is it correct to use "drink" and omit "to"?

Comment: Yep, in normal conditions the "to" would be omitted.

Comment: When both subject and verb are shared, and the repetitions are omitted, one may have the figure of speech "[syllepsis ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_and_syllepsis#Syllepsis)" as in the classic line "he hastened to put out the cat, the wine, his cigar and the lamps" from "Have Some Madeira M'Dear"" by Flanders ans Swann.